# "no matching index found" when using Google Cloud Firestore via Datastore library

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Google Cloud Platform project with Datastore configured in Firestore mode, where the following (Python) code produces a `google.api_core.exceptions.FailedPrecondition: 400 no matching index found.` error.

```
from google.cloud import datastore

store = datastore.Client(project='my-project')
query = store.query(kind='my-kind')
query.add_filter('start_date', '<', 1500000000)
results = query.fetch()
for r in results:  # error thrown here
    print(r)
```

As Firestore automatically indexes single fields (and I have not excluded the `start_timestamp` field from this automatic indexing) I would expect this to work. What am I doing wrong?

(Note that this works perfectly on another project where Datastore is in Datastore rather than Firestore mode; the project I happen to need to use unfortunately already has Firestore in place. As Firestore is supposed to be backwards-compatible with Datastore, I had hoped this would *just work*.)

Answer (score 1):

As Jim Morrison indicated, you need to use the Firestore library.

```py
from google.cloud import firestore
db = firestore.Client()
# [START get_simple_query]
docs = db.collection(u'my-collection').where(u'start_date', u'<=', 1500000000).stream()

for doc in docs:
    print(u'{} => {}'.format(doc.id, doc.to_dict()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, indexes are different between Firestore native & Firestore in Datastore mode.  You'll need to use the matching client to get your queries to work.  I suggest you use the [google-cloud-firestore](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-firestore/) python libraries instead of the google-cloud-datastore libraries.